# Perfect forwarding of a braced initializer to a constructor?

Tags: c++, braced-init-list

There are similar questions, but none seem to be quite this.

I have a wrapper class that exists to hold an `S`. In it's simplest form we have

```
// A simple class with a two-argument constructor:
struct S {
    int x[2];
    S(int x, int y) : x{x, y} {}
};

struct WrappedSSimple {
    S s;
    template <typename... Args>
    WrappedSSimple(Args&&... args) : s(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

which seems to work when I call `WrappedSSimple({1,2})`. However, I want to make the c'tor private and have a static factory function. That fails:

```
struct WrappedS {
    S s;
    template <typename... Args>
    static WrappedS make(Args&&... args) { return WrappedS(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
private:
    template <typename... Args>
    WrappedS(Args&&... args) : s(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

with

```
<source>:28:14: error: no matching function for call to 'make'
    auto w = WrappedS::make({1,2}); // This is not.
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:21: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack <(no value)> for template parameter 'Args'
    static WrappedS make(Args&&... args) { return WrappedS(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
                    ^
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rsWK94Thq

Is there a way to perfectly forward the braces through the `static` `make` function?

Comment: Are you trying to do, simply, `auto w = WrappedS::make(1,2);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example `WrappedSSimple({1,2})` is calling the move-constructor of `WrappedSSimple` with the a temporary constructed via the user-defined constructor as argument.

You cannot replicate this behavior with a factory if the constructor is private, because the temporary object which needs access to the constructor is always created in the context of the caller.

You can also not generally forward untyped braces. The best you can do, if you are fine with restricting the types to be the same for each element of the brace, is to use a `std::initializer_list` or a reference to an array as parameter to `make`.

Comment: I see. So if I want to make the calling code, I need to add, e.g., `static WrappedS make(S s) { return WrappedS(std::move(s)); }`, but there's no way to generally forward the (un-typed) `{1,2}` without the called function having an overload taking a type.

Comment: @Ben Yes, accepting a `S` would also work in this case. This can then also be overloaded for `S&&` and `const S&`. You just cannot rely on template argument deduction to deduce braces that have no associated type.

Comment: For practical purposes, can you think of a reason for both `const S&` and `S&&` versus `S` by value and moving it?

Comment: @Ben Taking the argument by-value will do one move construction more than taking by-reference if the object isn't constructed directly in the argument. That usually doesn't matter much, but you did ask for perfect forwarding, which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: Sure. I appreciate it. My point is that in reality, I know compilers can and do optimize out the temporary in `f(S s) { return g(std::move(s)); }` so I was trying to think if there was ever a case that there was a practical reason to do `f(const S& s) { return g(s); }` and `f(S&& s) { return g(std::move(s)); }` instead. I can't think of one. My habit these days has been to just provide the by-value version with the thought that if I ever see a perf hot spot I can do the `&&` and `const&` versions, but I've never seen it.

Comment: @Ben I agree that it is probably better to take by-value, but e.g. if the function or the move constructor is not defined in the translation unit where it is used, then optimization (without link-time optimization) may not be able to optimize out the temporary.